# PSD.rb rendering layer comp to png takes a long time and does not produce correct image

Tags: ruby, psd

I am trying to use PSD.rb to generate preview PNGs based on layer comps. When I run the script it takes roughly 12 minutes to produce 1 PNG.

This seems like quite a long time to me, as the PSD in not overly complicated. There are ~30 layers of which ~10 have filters, masks, etc...

The image size is 1800 x 1114 @ 72ppi. Is it reasonable for PSD.rb to take this long?

Besides the amount of time it takes the real issue is that the outputted PNG does not look like the layer comp. Pieces of the Comp are there but there are major discrepancies.

Does PSD.rb have issues applying items like masks, filters, or anything of the like?

Does anyone know how I might troubleshoot this?

In the documentation they mention adding `PSD.debug = true` This dumps a bunch of output but nothing really seems to jump out as problematic.

Here is a link to the lib: https://github.com/layervault/psd.rb

The script I have created is very simple:

```
require 'psd'
psd = PSD.new('dusk.psd')
psd.parse!
psd.tree.filter_by_comp('Layer Comp 1').save_as_png('./Version A.png')
```